# Remove commas from database column

Tags: sql

Basically in a table I want to remove all commas in `metadata_value` column entries someone put in where meta_key column is equal to 15, 16, or 17

So:

```
SELECT REPLACE(metadata_value, ',', '')
FROM project_content_to_metadata
WHERE metadata_key = '15'
AND metadata_key = '16'
AND metadata_key = '17'
```

But it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually want to remove the commas *in the table*, then use `update`:

```
update project_content_to_metadata
    set metadata_value =  REPLACE(metadata_value, ',', '')
    where metadata_key in (15, 16, 17);
```

Otherwise Kamil's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Your `REPLACE` is correct, but use `OR` instead of `AND`. One row can't have 3 different values. You could use `IN` to specify multiple `OR` conditions on one column:

```
SELECT REPLACE(metadata_value, ',', '')
FROM project_content_to_metadata
WHERE metadata_key IN ('15','16','17')
```

Also, if your `metadata_key` is of type Integer do not use quotes around values, so this could be:

```
metadata_key IN (15,16,17)
```